# Mannually connecting Flash Player (debug) to Flex/Flash Builder

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3

Is it at all possible to connect the Flash Player debug version to the debugger in Flex Builder using source code? I'm running an app which has no right click menu, and I therefore can't right click and select connect to debugger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to connect fdb.exe from the command line to my app! Works like a charm. A bit more work though, since there's no UI.

Comment: If you figured out by yourself how to do something, please consider providing some details for others who have the same question. Unless it's simply "use `callCMD(...)`".

Comment: Still, others might have the same problem nonetheless. Always provide an explanation with your answer. An answer like "it works now" doesn't help anyone. Although in this case, with Flash Player being discontinued and removed from most browsers soon, it's probably obsolete indeed. The problem's age alone is no reason to not explain the solution in more detail, though. Just some general SE advice.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you can connect it from code, by this maybe helps you:

If you want to run the Flex Builder with the Flash Player Debug you have first to get the [Flash Player Debug](http://www.adobe.com/support/flashplayer/downloads.html) then copy the Flash Player Debug into `[Flex Install Directory]\Player\win`, paste the Flash Player executable file and rename it to Flash Player.exe. Restart your Builder and run your application (from the Builder) in Debug Mode.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I'm already using the debug version. The problem is, my Flash movie can't run standalone, it's inside a C++ wrapper layer. I did manage to connect FDB though, so that's proof that a connection is at least possible.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you need: http://livedocs.adobe.com/livecycle/es/sdkHelp/programmer/lcds/debugging_03.html#182352

Comment: This appears the most feasible possibility at present. Managed to get FDB connected to our embedded Flash Player! So, inching forward, and inch at a time. :) Now I just need to encourage Flash Builder to listen for the connection. Doesnt FB use FDB.exe for debugging?