# Flex Hero: Android phone can't connect to Flash Debugger

Tags: android, apache-flex

I am building an Android application using Flex Hero.
When I run the application I can package it fine on my mobile and run it on the device, however, as soon as I want to run in debug mode on the device, the device gives me a message like: "Can't connect to debugger (192.168.1.12). Enter IP-address or hostname"

The device is connected with a USB to the PC and USB debugging is enabled on the device.
I have tried to shut down the computer's firewall, but no result.

Any ideas on which other things I may look at?

Thanks,
Anton

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some thoughts:

1. Reinstall the debugger.  Sometimes installation can poop out on me, and a reinstallation can help.
2. Check your security settings.  The debugger runs and a specific port, and this might be blocked on the firewall.  Make sure your ports are open for this (the debugger runs on port 7935 I think by default).
3. Restart Flex Builder.  I've had issues before where you disconnect a debugging session and the SWFs are not properly unloaded.
4. Add a breakpoint to your app (sometimes this works)
5. Use [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1459532/mannually-connecting-flash-player-debug-to-flex-flash-builder) to manually connect to your debugger (if possible).

Comment: Thanks. I am not sure what the actual solution was. Maybe reinstalling the debugger helped. I am now on Flash Builder 4.5 (before I was using burrito) and the latest version flash debug player, it now works fine on a Samsung Galaxy S.